# Parse alternatives for sending push notifications user to user (device to device)?

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, push-notification

I am looking for a iOS push notification service that allows user to user (device to device) push notifications fairly straight forwardly.

I have been using Parse for this, but it is shutting down in a couple weeks. I just tried Urban Airship (because they promised the same capabilities as Parse), however found out after setting everything up that they do not provide this user to user capability.

What service would you recommend for sending pushes user to user? I use Firebase for the database for the app.

Thanks!!

Comment: How exactly do you mean user-user? Like if you want to make it where a user sends a message to another user, it then fires a push notification to the recipient, you can do so easily with CloudKit. If you're already an Apple Developer it will be free for you (to a certain extent)

Comment: Sorry I was a bit unclear. What I mean is a service that automatically routes a payload from a device to the apple cloud and routes it back to a different device for push notification. Such as if it was a game app with two users (User A and B) and User A won the game, user B would receive a push stating that User A won. Would this be possible with CloudKit?

Comment: Yes something like that could be accomplished in theory. You can set a user to essentially listen for updates within a certain record, and if a condition is met send a push notification. So you could have something like a record named `Game` and then `userA` and `userB`, where `userB` could be registered to receive notifications whenever a field named `gameFinished` is set to true. It would take some experimentation but it could be done. I migrated an app from Parse to CloudKit back when they announced it was being shut down.

Comment: I still don't understand why Facebook shut down Parse. Or why did they even buy it in the first place? They obviously never had any intentions of keeping it around. It was a great tool for independent developers. I still haven't seen a great alternative for beginners take it's place. Amazon Web Services is by and far the best I've used, but it has quite the learning curve.

Comment: Awesome, great to know thanks!